# Compare two lists and pull values from a 3rd column based on where match was found

Tags: google-sheets

I am pretty sure I need to use MATCH but can't quite get it working.

For Example

Sheet1

```
a
b
c
d
```

Sheet2

```
a 1
d 4
```

Desired sheet1

```
a 1
b (blank/empty)
c (blank/empty)
d 4
```

Comment: I thought it would be something like
=ARRAYFORMULA((IFERROR(MATCH(A$2:A,Sheet2!C$2:C,0),TempCat!D2))) but that means the # after D is based on the row in original sheet not Sheet2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is not the text `(blank/empty)` that you want but rather a seemingly empty cell and that `a` in both sheets is in cell A1, please try in Sheet1 B1:

```
=iferror(vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A$1:B$4,2,0),"")
```

and copy down to suit.
[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

`IFERROR` tests the result of the lookup function (which will return an error where the sought value is not found) and returns a 'blank' with `""`.

Answer (score -1):

Vlookup was the way to go here is the final version:

```
=IFERROR(vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A$1:B,2,false),"")
```